# How to rotate a text line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty, legend style={at={(0.95,0.50)},anchor=north east}]



     \addplot3[no marks,red] coordinates{  ( 0 , 0.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.2 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.3 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.5 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.6 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.7 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.8 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.9 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.0 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.2 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.3 , 1-5.00015000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.6 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.7 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.8 , 1-5.00002000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.9 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.1 , 1-4.99983000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.2 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.3 , 1-5.00004000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.4 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.5 , 1-4.99989000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.6 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.7 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.8 , 1-4.99986000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.9 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.0 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.1 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.3 , 1-4.99829000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.4 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.5 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.6 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.7 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.8 , 1-5.00008000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.9 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.0 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.1 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.3 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.4 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.6 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.7 , 1-4.99998000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.8 , 1-5.00017000000000 )  };




\end{axis}  

\draw[ ] (1,-.5,0) node{Rounds 10 to 20};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

How can I  rotate the line "Rounds 10 to 20" by -30 degree angle?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the style `[rotate=-30]` to the node you want to rotate:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty, legend style={at={(0.95,0.50)},anchor=north east}]
     \addplot3[no marks,red] coordinates{  ( 0 , 0.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.2 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.3 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.5 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.6 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.7 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.8 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.9 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.0 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.2 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.3 , 1-5.00015000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.6 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.7 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.8 , 1-5.00002000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.9 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.1 , 1-4.99983000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.2 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.3 , 1-5.00004000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.4 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.5 , 1-4.99989000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.6 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.7 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.8 , 1-4.99986000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.9 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.0 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.1 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.3 , 1-4.99829000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.4 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.5 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.6 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.7 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.8 , 1-5.00008000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.9 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.0 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.1 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.3 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.4 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.6 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.7 , 1-4.99998000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.8 , 1-5.00017000000000 )  };
\end{axis}
\draw[ ] (1,-.5,0) node [rotate=-30] {Rounds 10 to 20};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated node]

If you simply wants a sloped label for the x axis, you can simply use `xlabel`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty, legend style={at={(0.95,0.50)},anchor=north east},xlabel style = {sloped},xlabel={Rounds 10 to 20}]
     \addplot3[no marks,red] coordinates{  ( 0 , 0.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.2 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.3 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.5 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.6 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.7 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.8 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 0.9 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.0 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.1 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.2 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.3 , 1-5.00015000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.4 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.6 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.7 , 1-5.00001000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.8 , 1-5.00002000000000 ) ( 0 , 1.9 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.0 , 1-4.99991000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.1 , 1-4.99983000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.2 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.3 , 1-5.00004000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.4 , 1-4.99993000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.5 , 1-4.99989000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.6 , 1-4.99997000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.7 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.8 , 1-4.99986000000000 ) ( 0 , 2.9 , 1-5.00007000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.0 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.1 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.3 , 1-4.99829000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.4 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.5 , 1-4.99994000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.6 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.7 , 1-4.99995000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.8 , 1-5.00008000000000 ) ( 0 , 3.9 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.0 , 1-4.99996000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.1 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.2 , 1-5.00003000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.3 , 1-4.99999000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.4 , 1-5.00021000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.5 , 1-5.00000000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.6 , 1-5.00005000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.7 , 1-4.99998000000000 ) ( 0 , 4.8 , 1-5.00017000000000 )  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sloped label]